# Is this question "impossible" or "too localized"?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304970/max-number-of-souls-dark-souls-2-sotfs-ps4) Is a question I recently found on stack exchange.

On the one hand, finding this out seems to be an extremely difficulty and tedious task. There seems to be very little reason to figure this out other than curiosity.

On the other hand, curiosity is a valid reason to ask a question. Furthermore, it is possible that many people would be curious about this question. Maybe someone wants to plan a build or something. It is also possible that the question is not as hard to answer as it seems. If there is a list of every enemy in the game and their drops, a spread sheet could be used to figure out the answer.

Is this question acceptable. If not, why?

Comment: An expert answer doesn't necessarily need to do the legwork of farming souls until they hit some limit. I think the comment from Question Marks makes the most sense - if you can continually farm for new souls, then there is no limit other than that imposed by the game/system ('unsigned long long' at most??). That would be the basis of a good answer.

Comment: I think the question is acceptable, although I personally don't find it a really useful or interesting one. I could understand why someone would downvote it, but it doesn't need to be closed. A question can still be OK, even though the answer may be that there is no definitive answer, as long as there can be an explanation for it and a way to research the issue, like Ben's answer to the question shows.